# Whats the common way to setup a websocket client in ROS2 robot?

Tags: callback, thread, rosbridge-suite, websocket

### Design Concept

[image: ros2 client websocket implementation design]

### Questions

As stated in the title, I am working on a robot that required to **send out it state information** (safety and monitoring purpose) to a remote backend server. Meanwhile, maintain **listening to the server for any task request or cancellation request of task**. The backend team decided to use **websocket** as a communication protocol. To test our own websocket client, I borrowed the Websocket server from FastAPI (see [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/)). I am planning to create one or two ros2 node with python, depends on wether I should break the send() and recv() into two nodes.

I would like to keep the websocket-node running, meanwhile the websocket can do it jobs without blocking the callback of websocket-node (timer_callback is not working under my implementation).

#### main.py (server)

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>WebSocket Chat</h1>
        <h2>Your ID: <span id="ws-id"></span></h2>
        <form action="" onsubmit="sendMessage(event)">
            <input type="text" id="messageText" autocomplete="off"/>
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>
        <ul id='messages'>
        </ul>
        <script>
            var client_id = Date.now()
            document.querySelector("#ws-id").textContent = client_id;
            var ws = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:8000/ws/${client_id}`);
            ws.onmessage = function(event) {
                var messages = document.getElementById('messages')
                var message = document.createElement('li')
                var content = document.createTextNode(event.data)
                message.appendChild(content)
                messages.appendChild(message)
            };
            function sendMessage(event) {
                var input = document.getElementById("messageText")
                ws.send(input.value)
                input.value = ''
                event.preventDefault()
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
"""


class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active_connections: list[WebSocket] = []

    async def connect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.accept()
        self.active_connections.append(websocket)

    def disconnect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        self.active_connections.remove(websocket)

    async def send_personal_message(self, message: str, websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.send_text(message)

    async def broadcast(self, message: str):
        for connection in self.active_connections:
            await connection.send_text(message)


manager = ConnectionManager()


@app.get("/")
async def get():
    return HTMLResponse(html)


@app.websocket("/ws/{client_id}")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, client_id: int):
    await manager.connect(websocket)
    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            await manager.send_personal_message(f"You wrote: {data}", websocket)
            await manager.broadcast(f"Client #{client_id} says: {data}")
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        manager.disconnect(websocket)
        await manager.broadcast(f"Client #{client_id} left the chat")
```

I have searched the Internet, and coming down to below throughs:

1. rosbridge-suit
2. websockets library with asyncio (I am not familiar with asyncio)
3. websockets library with threading
4. websocket-client library

For rosbright-suit, actually I am not sure is it the right way to use it, as many use it as a server instead of a client side... Most client is hosted in the remote side (for example a JS webpage or Mobile app) instead of robot itself. I need more guidance for this.

For the rest, the problem come down to threading, I/O issue when working with ROS2 node. I have tried to implement it with `websockets with asyncio` but the result is not ideal and the code is hard to maintain and scale. Below is the code:

#### ros-websocket-client.py (client)

```py
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

import asyncio
import websockets
import json

from std_msgs.msg import Bool
from charging_robot_system_msgs.msg import ChargingRobotState
from sensor_msgs.msg import BatteryState


connection_state = False

class WebsocketClient(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('websocket_client')
        
        # Publisher
        self.connection_state_pub_ = self.create_publisher(
            Bool, '/charging_robot/connection_state', 10)

        # Subscriber
        self.battery_state_sub_ = self.create_subscription(
            BatteryState, '/charging_robot/status/battery_state', self.battery_state_callback, 1)

        # Timer
        # timer_period = 3  # seconds
        # self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)

        # Initial
        self.battery_state_: BatteryState = None
        self.battery_previous_timestamp_ = 0
        self.connection_state = False

    def publish_connection_state(self):
        msg = Bool()
        msg.data = self.connection_state
        self.publish_connection_state(msg)
    
    def battery_state_callback(self, msg: BatteryState):
        # print('[+] Updated battery state')    # debug
        self.battery_state_ = msg


def serialize_data(data):
    return json.dumps(data)

def deserialize_data(serialized_data):
    return json.loads(serialized_data)

"""
Consumer
"""
async def recv_from_server(websocket):
    async for message in websocket:
        print(message)

"""
Producer
"""
async def send_to_server(websocket, node):
    while rclpy.ok():
        global connection_state
        msg: BatteryState = node.battery_state_
        if connection_state == True:
            if msg is not None and (msg.header.stamp.sec - node.battery_previous_timestamp_ > 3.0):
                battery_data = {
                'robot_id': '001',  # dummy id
                'timestamp': msg.header.stamp.sec,
                'power_supply_status': msg.power_supply_status,
                'temperature': msg.temperature,
                'soc_percentage': msg.percentage,
                'voltage': msg.voltage,
                'current': msg.current
                }
                serialized_battery_data = serialize_data(battery_data)
                node.battery_previous_timestamp_ = msg.header.stamp.sec
                await websocket.send(serialized_battery_data)
                print('[+] Message sent')
            else:
                print('[-] Battery state data is not ready or updated yet')
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

async def handler(node ,websocket):
    await asyncio.gather(
        recv_from_server(websocket),
        send_to_server(websocket, node),
    )

async def connect_to_server(node):
    global connection_state
    uri = 'ws://localhost:8000/ws/001'
    async for websocket in websockets.connect(uri):
        try:
            print('[+] Connected to server')
            connection_state = True
            await handler(node, websocket)
        except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
            print('[-] Fail to connect server')
            connection_state = False
            continue

async def spin_node(node):
    while rclpy.ok():
        rclpy.spin_once(node, timeout_sec=0.1)
        await asyncio.sleep(0)


async def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    websocket_client = WebsocketClient()

    await asyncio.gather(
        spin_node(websocket_client),
        connect_to_server(websocket_client),
    )

    websocket_client.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Currently this client can publish and listen to the remote server, but I still havent implemnet the logic to transform the data and publish it back to ROS message. I am not sure where to trigger the method call.

As I have stated in very beginning, I am not familiar with asyncio, thus most of the code is drafted in a try-and-error manner. I dont even know how some of them could work. Therefore, I would like to start a question here. To see if anyone has done this kind of things before, and can share a common way to do this kind of websocket interface between robot and remote server.

Remark: *The battery state msg is published by another dummy node to allow this node to trigger its callback.*

Answer (score 1):

I would use a synchronous websocket client like [websocket-client](https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), and run it in a separate thread from the ros code. My advice is to keep your ros code and your websocket code as separated as you can. Your ros code could use a Timer to periodically check if your websocket class has a command-from-the-server waiting for it.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up a ros2 websocket bridge node using python websockets library.

You can find it in my GitHub [repo](https://github.com/TZECHIN6/ros2websocket). Any suggestion is welcome! I have tested it and so far it doing great.

Thanks for all the comments :D I agree with Mike that separate the interface as much as possible for easy code management.

Comment: Add some details/instructions on github for how to use it. Newbs like me might find it useful but need some guidance. +1 for posting the link.

Comment: Sure! You could also leave issue if you find difficulties on using that. I would plan to update it within this weekend

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, in this method:

```py
async def recv_from_server(websocket):
    async for message in websocket:
        print(message)
```

You can modify it like this:

```py
async def recv_from_server(websocket):
    async for message in websocket:
        msg = Bool()
        msg.data = message  # Assuming the message from the server is of type bool
        self.connection_state_pub_.publish(msg)
```

This is a straightforward example of how to receive a non-ROS message and create a ROS message. You can find the ROS `Bool` message definition here: [ROS Bool Message](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Bool.html).